# Undefined property exception when dispatching laravel queues

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have the following error when I dispatch a Laravel job and I don't understand where the problem is coming from :

> ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Jobs\SendMenus::$menu in
> C:\laragon\www\webapp_adminLTE\app\Jobs\SendMenus.php:38  Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\laragon\www\webapp_adminLTE\app\Jobs\SendMenus.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8,
>
> 'Undefined prope...', 'C:\laragon\www\...', 38, Array)  #1
> [internal function]:
> App\Jobs\SendMenus->handle(Object(App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController))

The job in question :

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


class SendMenus implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $order;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(OrdersController $ordersController){
        $order = $this->order;

//        $ordersController = new OrdersController();

        $menuFile = $ordersController->templateEdition($order->id);

        Mail::send([], [], function($message) use($menuFile,$order){
            $customerName = $order->customer->first_name . ' ' . $order->customer->last_name;

            $message->attach($menuFile,
                [
                    'as' => 'menu.pdf',
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf'
                ]);
            $message->to($order->customer->email_address);
            $message->subject('Today\'s Menu Eatology');
            $message->setBody(
                'Good Morning ' . $customerName . ',' . '<br/>' .
                'Please find the attached menu for today.' . '<br/>' . '<br/>' .
                'Have a nice day.' . '<br/>' .
                'Best regards,' . '<br/>' .
                'Eatology'
                , 'text/html');
            $message->cc('XXXX@eatologyasia.com');
        });
    }
}
```

All the methods called in this job are working perfectly when called outside of this queue. I think the ordersController is not declared properly or something but I'm not sure yet.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe extending the Controller will work.

For example:

class SendMenus extends ordersController implements ShouldQueue
{
}

Comment: I tried it but got the error : Cannot make non static method App\Http\Controllers\Controller::dispatch() static in class Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable.

Thanks for the help though !